# Excel INDEX LOOKUP VLOOKUP HLOOKUP Combination

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have some paths defined by geodetical coordinates and some points also defined by coordinates.
I am trying without success to find the exact or nearest path in which the points lie on or are nearby.
My table looks like that:

```
                        Path-Start               Path-End                    
ID    vs      ID     East       North        East       North            Point    East      North
1-A    600    1-A    366,585    7,270,720    366,704    7,270,700        L-01    366,887    7,269,446
1-B    525    1-B    366,704    7,270,700    366,822    7,270,682        L-02    366,822    7,269,546
1-C    519    1-C    366,822    7,270,682    366,939    7,270,663        L-03    366,757    7,269,446
1-D    629,4  1-D    366,939    7,270,663    367,056    7,270,645        L-04    366,822    7,269,346
2      728,3    2    365,995    7,270,467    366,145    7,270,469        M-01    366,822    7,269,466
3      646,2    3    367,421    7,270,465    367,561    7,270,465        M-02    366,973    7,269,466
4      429,7    4    367,726    7,270,470    367,875    7,270,472        M-04    366,671    7,269,466
5      759,4    5    365,857    7,270,216    366,011    7,270,216        M-06    366,585    7,269,622
6,1    888,6    6,1  366,072    7,270,217    366,192    7,270,217        M-07    366,746    7,269,613
6,2    741,2    6,2  366,192    7,270,217    366,312    7,270,217        M-08    366,898    7,269,613
6,3    570,3    6,3  366,312    7,270,217    366,432    7,270,217        M-09    367,062    7,269,618
7,1    481,6    7,1  366,572    7,270,216    366,726    7,270,216        M-10    366,582    7,269,314
7,2    444,7    7,2  366,726    7,270,216    366,88    7,270,216        M-11    366,746    7,269,319
7,3    556    7,3    366,88    7,270,216    367,034    7,270,216        M-12    366,896    7,269,319
8,1    936,9    8,1  367,425    7,270,220    367,576    7,270,223        M-13    367,035    7,269,309
8,2    422,7    8,2  367,577    7,270,223    367,739    7,270,216        M-15    366,659    7,269,780
8,3    412,8    8,3  367,74    7,270,215    367,89    7,270,216        M-16    366,822    7,269,780
9      574,3    9    365,662    7,269,966    365,816    7,269,966        M-17    366,985    7,269,780
10     534,6    10    367,827    7,269,966    367,981    7,269,966        M-20    366,659    7,269,152
11,1   761,3   11,1    365,552    7,269,716    365,652    7,269,716        M-21    366,822    7,269,152
11,2    664,9  11,2    365,652    7,269,716    365,752    7,269,716        M-22    366,985    7,269,152
12    660,8    12    365,887    7,269,716    366,041    7,269,716        M-24    366,828    7,270,048
13    1156,5    13    366,252    7,269,716    366,406    7,269,716        M-25    366,816    7,268,884
14,1    524,9    14,1    366,522    7,269,716    366,676    7,269,716        S-03    366,661    7,269,259
14,2    411,1    14,2    366,676    7,269,716    366,83    7,269,716        S-04    366,983    7,269,259
14,3    395,3    14,3    366,83    7,269,716    366,984    7,269,716        S-05    366,399    7,269,635
```

The point (for example L-01) has the coordinates at the right of it. I have to find accordingly to its coordinates to which path-ID it belongs and then write the vs value of the path.
Any help or ideas are much appreciated.

Comment: What output do you expect from given data? What is logic to achieve that?

Comment: Hallo Harun, i just gave my real data in order to accelerate the question . I could change them but without any reason. I expect an output that sais that the point L-01 has a vs of 556, for example, in case the point lies on the PATH-ID 7,3

Comment: To clarify more my question, first of all I need to find out to which path belongs each point. The paths are given with two points (Start and End of the path). These two points are also given by coordinates. I have to assign each point in one path. More points can be assigned to one path. The points also can be lie not ON but near the patf, that means, that I have to compare the coordinates in a way that the nearest path is to be found. After that step, lowwols the easy part of assign the vs-parameter at each point.

Comment: I think we need a bit of context - my first thought is if the distances are relatively small, you could just use plane geometry https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line. I don't think many people will be familiar with geodetical coordinates (I'm not) but I understand that there are a number of different systems in use? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodetic_datum#Geodetic_coordinates If the distances are too small for approximation, I imagine the spherical or ellipsoidal geometry is quite hard.

Comment: @Tom Sharpe: you are right. However one must not have geodetical knowledge. But the knowlegde how a line with two point sis defined may be necessary. I have thoought that a  simple IF Function could be adequate. The east coordinate of the point must be between the east cooridnate of the two points of the line (=path) and at the same time the same must happens for the north ordinate. However, this worls only when the point coordinates lie on the line. In case they lie next to the line it is more difficult to define a relationship.

Comment: Could you show an example of what you're using for your search and what's the expected result(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your question is really about how to "find the exact or nearest path", I will focus on that and ignore the mechanics of calculating that distance.

**Modifying the Problem to Focus on the Question**

I will replace the **Distance from a point to a line or geodetic line** with a simpler to understand **Cartesian distance between two points**.  So, in my metaphorical formulation, I am going to find the nearest **vs** based on `[Point East, Point North]` versus `[Path Start East, Path Start North]` and `[Path End East, Path End North]` in a reformulated version of your table, but put into an Excel Table to make it more readable and easier to understand. §

[image]

I will replace your unknown-to-me distance calculation with my oversimplified dummy formula based on pythagoras distance that looks at each Point's distance to Path Start and Path End and adds them.  So, it is effectively:

```
SQRT( ([Pt E]-[Path.St E])^2 + ([Pt N] - [Path.St N])^2 ) +
SQRT( ([Pt E]-[Path.End E])^2 + ([Pt N] - [Path.End N])^2 )
```

**Solving the Lookup Problem**

*Hoping you have Excel 365 - otherwise, this has to be done differently and with helper cells...*

I created a column at the end of your table that holds the result of the nearest **vs** based on the minimum "distance".  The important part of the formula below is the use of INDEX, which I think is your question in the first place - INDEX is the best approach.

```
=LET( pythDist, SQRT( ([@[Point East]]-[Path-Start East])^2 + ([@[Point North]] - [Path-Start North])^2 ) 
                      + SQRT( ([@[Point East]]-[Path-End East])^2 + ([@[Point North]] - [Path-End North])^2 ),
       INDEX( [vs], MATCH( MIN( pythDist ), pythDist, 0 ) ) )
```

This first takes in your variables for the distance calculation (Point East, Point North, [Path Start North], [Path Start East], [Path Start North], [Path End East]) and calculates my fake distance called **pythDist**.  In this line, you need to put in the real calculation of distance that you are going to use.  The most important point is:

> When you refer to your **path starts** and **ends**, put in the entire range
> of values - i.e. the whole column.  For example, in my worksheet your
> Path-Start East is in D2:D27 - you have to put that whole range in
> place and **locked $D$2:$D$27** *if you are not using an Excel table* or
> column name **[Path-Start East]** *if you are using an Excel table*.
>
> When referring to your **points**, refer to the individual cells using
> **relative addressing**. i.e. I2 in my workbook for Point East first value
> or **[@[Point East]]** *using Excel table addressing*.

So **pythDist** is actually evaluating each point against all of the path variables to create a **column of results** that contain the distances.  That's what you need to accomplish in your calculation by replacing my dummy formula with your real one.

Then the process of locating the **vs**, is now simply done by INDEX.  You put the **[vs]** column *(or locked range)* into the array part of INDEX and then use MATCH to find the location of the minimum distance value within **pythDist**.

**Notes**

If you don't have Excel 365, you can still do this, but it is messy.  If you need help on how to do that - say so in the comments and I can give it a try.  LET makes things so much cleaner.

§ - To make an Excel Table, make sure that your header row has unique and representative field names (i.e. change [North] to [Path Start North], etc.).  Then click anywhere in the table and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.  Excel will ask if your table has headers - say yes.